# PDF of sums of independent random variables confusion

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, random-variables

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent continuous RVs with PDFs $f_X$ and $f_Y$ respectively.

I want to find the PDF of $Z = X + Y$.

The CDF of $X + Y$ is

$$F_{X+Y}(z) = P(X + Y \leq z)$$
$$=\int\int_{\{(x,y):x+y\leq z\}}f_X(x)f_Y(y)dx dy$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_Y(y) \bigg\{{\int_{-\infty}^{z-y}f_X(x)dx\bigg\}dy}$$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^\infty F_X(z-y)f_Y(y)dy$$

Now this is all jolly good, but my problem is with deriving a PDF from this. I know that we have:

$$f_{X+Y}(z) = \frac{d}{dz} F_{X+Y}(z)$$

But after this point, I am confused. My professor says the derivation continues like so:

$$f_{X+Y}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d}{dz} F_X(z-y)f_Y(y)dy$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(z-y)f_Y(y)dy$$

So my two questions are:

1) Why does the $\frac{d}{dz}$ jump inside the integral? Why are we not writing: $$f_{X+Y}(z)= \frac{d}{dz}\int_{-\infty}^\infty F_X(z-y)f_Y(y)dy$$

2) Why does $\frac{d}{dz} F_X(z-y) = f_X(z-y) $?

Comment: 1) : unspoken regularity conditions, 2): chain rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Why does the $d/dz$ jump inside the integral?

Under some conditions (which most "decent" functions follow) you can interchange derivation and integration operations. If the extremes of integration depend on the variable $z$ (not the case here) then it's gets a littler more complex. For the general form, and for the precise conditions, see [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

> 2. Why does $\frac{d}{dz} F_X(z-y) = f_X(z-y)$

You are supposed to know that $F_X$ a primitive of $f_X$, then $F_X'=f_X$

Because here the funcion is applied, not to the variable $z$ but to a function of it, we apply the chain rule.

$$\frac{d}{dz} F_X(g(z)) = f_X(g(z)) \frac{d g(z)}{dz} $$

Here $g(z)=z-y$, and it's derivative is $1$.